# xgboost superslow on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, xgboost

I am trying to train a list of R caret models on Google Cloud Compute Engine (Ubuntu LTS16.04). The xgboost (both xgblinear and xgbtree) model took forever to complete the training. In fact, the CPU utilization is always 0 from GCP status monitoring.

I used doMC library for parallel execution. It works very well for models like C5.0, glmnet and gbm. However, for xgboost (both xgblinear and xgbtree),due to some reason, the CPU seems not running because the utilization remains 0. Troubleshooting:
1. Removed the doMC and run with single core only, same problem remained. 
2. Changed the parallel execution library to doParallel instead of doMC. This round the CPU utilization went up, but it took 5 mins to complete the training on GCP. The same codes finished in just 12 seconds on my local laptop. (I ran 24 CPUs on GCP, and 4 CPUs on my local laptop)
3. The doMC parallel execution works well for other algorithm. Only xgboost has this problem.

Code:

```
xgblinear_Grid <- expand.grid(nrounds = c(50, 100),
                              lambda = c(.05,.5),
                              alpha = c(.5),
                              eta = c(.3))

registerDoMC(cores = mc - 1)
set.seed(123)
xgbLinear_varimp <- train(formula2, data=train_data, method="xgbLinear", metric=metric, tuneGrid = xgblinear_Grid, trControl=fitControl, preProcess = c("center", "scale", "zv"))

print(xgbLinear_varimp)
```

No error message generated. It simply runs endlessly.[R sessionInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3sRe.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and it took a long time to understand the three reasons behind it:

1. `xgbLinear` requires more memory than any other machine learning algorithm available in the caret library. For every core, you can assume at least 1GB RAM even for tiny datasets of only 1000 x 20 dimension, for bigger datasets more.
2. `xgbLinear` in combination with parallel execution has a final process that recollects the data from the threads. This process is usually responsible for the 'endless' execution time. Again, the RAM is the limiting factor. You might have seen the following error message that which is often caused by to little allocation of RAM: 
   `Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection`
3. `xgbLinear` has its own parallel processing algorithm which gets mixed up with the `doParallel` algorithm. Here, the effective solution is to set xgbLinear to single-thread by an additional parameter in caret::train() - `nthread = 1` - and let doParallel do the parallelization

As illustration for (1), you can see here that the memory utilization nears 80 GB:
[image]

and 235GB for a training a still tiny dataset of 2500x14 dimensionality:
[image]

As illustration for (2), you can see here that this is the process that takes forever if you don't have enough memory:

[image]

Comment: @Derek Li if this answer solves your problem, please check it as the solution (small check sign below the upvote/downvote sign.